# php response is taking too long time

Tags: php, mysql, json, odbc, visual-foxpro

I have some problem with getting results from VFP database results... The time which is taking by my php script is veeeery long - about 30 minutes, but it should be much shorter...

So there is the code which is responsible for taking database results:

```
$connect = odbc_connect("RIS", "", "", SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER) or die("Error in connection ".  odbc_errormsg($connect));
    $array = array();
    $info = array();

    $from = $_GET['from'];
    $to = $_GET['to'];

    $rez_nap = odbc_exec($connect, "
                                        select
                                            pacientid as pac_pk,
                                            datanapr,
                                            ocered,
                                            rtgapparat,
                                            doctor as doc_naprav,
                                            pk_na,
                                            data_opis,
                                            arst_opis as id_arst_opis
                                        from
                                            napravlenie
                                        where
                                            not arst_opis == '0000' and
                                            not arst_opis == '' and
                                            datanapr between {^".$from."} and {^".$to."}
                        ") or die(odbc_errormsg());
    while($row_nap = odbc_fetch_array($rez_nap))
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($row_nap);

        $rez_opis = odbc_exec($connect, "
                                            select
                                                opis as opisanie,
                                                doctor as doc_opis
                                            from
                                                opisanie_rtg
                                            where
                                                pacientid = '".$row_nap["pac_pk"]."' and
                                                data = '".$row_nap["data_opis"]."' and
                                                ocered = '".$row_nap["ocered"]."'
                             ") or die(odbc_errormsg());
        while($row_desc = odbc_fetch_array($rez_opis))
        {
            $op = explode('@#$', $row_desc['opis']);
            $opisanie = iconv( "cp1257", "utf-8", trim( addslashes($op[1]) ) );
            $t_nr_i = substr($op[0], 12);
            $ttt = explode("[", $t_nr_i);

            if ( strlen($ttt[0]) > 12 )
            {
                $tt_nr_is = explode("-", $ttt[0]);
                $t_nr_is_t = substr($tt_nr_is[0], 0, 8);
                $t_nr_is_t_2 = substr($tt_nr_is[0], 8, 5);
                $row_desc["nr_is"] = $t_nr_is_t."-".$t_nr_is_t_2;
            }
            else
            {
                $t_nr_is_t = substr($ttt[0], 0, 8);
                $t_nr_is_t_2 = substr($ttt[0], 8, 5);
                $row_desc["nr_is"] = $t_nr_is_t."-".$t_nr_is_t_2;
            }
            $row_desc['opis'] = $opisanie;
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $rez_apparat = odbc_exec($connect, "
                                select
                                    kod,
                                    gruppa,
                                    imy,
                                    prefiks
                                from
                                    apparatura
                                where
                                    kod = '".$row_nap["rtgapparat"]."'
                  ") or die("Error in apparatura.dbf - ".  odbc_errormsg($connect));
            while($row_apparat = odbc_fetch_array($rez_apparat))
            {
                $rez_app_gruppa = odbc_exec($connect, "
                                                    select 
                                                        gruppa,
                                                        prefiks,
                                                        apparati
                                                    from
                                                        apparat_gruppa
                                                    where
                                                        gruppa = '".$row_apparat["gruppa"]."'
                                                 ") or die(error_logs("Error in apparat_gruppa.dbf - ".odbc_errormsg($connect)));
                while($row_app_gruppa = odbc_fetch_array($rez_app_gruppa))
                {
                    $rez_personal = odbc_exec($connect, "
                                                        select 
                                                            s_name as doc_opis_name,
                                                            f_name as doc_opis_surname
                                                        from
                                                            personal
                                                        where
                                                            number = '".$row_nap["id_doc_opis"]."'
                                                     ") or die(error_logs("Error in personal.dbf - ".odbc_errormsg($connect)));
                    while($row_personal = odbc_fetch_array($rez_personal))
                    {
                        $row_personal["doc_opis_name"] = iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", trim($row_personal["doc_opis_name"]));
                        $row_personal["doc_opis_surname"] = iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", trim($row_personal["doc_opis_surname"]));
                        $row_personal["filial"] = "r15";

                        $info[] = array_merge($row_nap, $row_desc, $row_apparat, $row_app_gruppa, $row_personal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($info);
    odbc_close($connect);
```

the database has about ~80-90k rows with data, and I'm using odbc driver to connect to VFP database, also the database is on the remote server... Any advices what I'm doing wrong? Because I can't figure what I'm doing wrong... Thanks for any advice and help!

P.S Also I need to convert that response into JSON and then save it to MySQL database...

**EDIT 1**
I have the second indexes:
pacientid, data_opis, ocered into the pacient table, opisanie and napravlenie

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging and timing of your script to figure out what part is taking a long time, once you have that data come back and trim your question down to just that part.

Comment: @cmorrissey it can be randome part of data one day it can be first and second select, then it can be foth or third select and so one...

Comment: Have you set indices on your database fields? So the database engine does not have to perform a full table scan each time it retrieves a value? Providing the table schema could be helpful...

Comment: @syck see my edit, for indexes which I have in tables, but I can't provide DB chema because I don't have permissions to get it...

Comment: So for example arst_opis in the first request is querying a condition on a non-indexed field, and there are others as well. You could also reduce the number of single SQL requests by using `JOIN`s.

Comment: You need to have the indexes. But that is not sufficient, your code is already trying to make it as slow as possible. Instead of doing thousands of selects inside those loops, try minimizing the SQL calls.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly that you are trying to migrate from an old VFP database into a MYSQL database. Couldn't it be an option to simply revert your idea. That is: write a small VFP app that would do the `SELECT`s on its native database type and then it could connect to `MYSQL` via `ODBC` and migrate the results. I think this way you could utilize the indexes and `Foxpro`s builtin `Rushmore` optimizer.